# Java Netbeans - Form blank after "clean and build"

Tags: java, netbeans, build, screen

I've got a little problem and I'm not sure what the cause could be.
I'm making a PacMan remake game in Java (Netbeans) and I'm using standard java classes for drawing components (JComponent, paintComponent, ...).
When I run the project from NetBeans (Run -> Run Project (PacMan)), it works fine. Everything is being drawn and everything is visible.

[This is how it looks when I run it directly from NetBeans [Run -> Run Project (PacMan)]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGJuc.png)

The problem comes when I try to "Clean and Build" the project, so that I can have ".jar" file and run it independently.
When I click on Run -> Clean and Build Project (PacMan), everything seems to be OK, however when I go to my Netbeans Projects -> PacMan -> dist -> PacMan.jar, and I run it, I am presented with a white blank screen.

[This is how it looks after "Clean and Build" in the "dist" folder.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ExASa.png)

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this? Thank you so much :)

Comment: At the first sight, you shouldn't dist the jar, rather dist the project...

Comment: @zlakad Could you please specify when you mean? I'm not sure if I'm doing this correctly. I tried right-clicking on the PacMan project in NetBeans and then clicking "Clean and Build". However I'm getting the same result.

Comment: I just posted an answer. Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the project and select properties. Select Deployment. Enable native packaging... Apply. Right click on the project again. Select `Package as...`
[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've done what you described, but I'm still (probably) getting the same result. Also, what should I package it as? The only one that actually works from these is "Image Only". Then an "exe" file gets created and when I run it, I'm still getting the white window.

Comment: I cannot tell you what is going on. Try to reinstall NetBeans.

Comment: I will try to do that. Thank you anyway.